# Query option 'Format' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

I'm getting an exception on my Web API controller endpoint and I would appreciate some help solving it.

Here is the story:

In my Web API project, a controller exposes the following endpoints:

[image]

My Kendo UI Datagrid makes the following request:

```
http://localhost:63865/api/employees/GetAll?$callback=jQuery21109420544053427875_1410883352953&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=5
```

I'm getting this exception when validating the ODataQueryOptions sent in the request:

> Query option 'Format' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.

[image]

But I've enabled all query options:

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions=AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally manage to get to the bottom of this!

After creating the ODataValidationSettings object I needed to change the AllowedQueryOptions to AllowedQueryOptions.All. Be default all options are there except the Format and SkipToken.

[image]

Anyway, hope this may help anyone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I had to solve it a different way.  My OData service controll was generated using Entity Framework (data first) and it turns out Microsoft's template doesn't support all the OData parameters. This puzzled me because I don't need the extra parameters anyway because I was just trying to define a datasource for use with a TreeView Kendo component. I finally found the Telerik blog post that went into detail about [Using Kendo UI With MVC4, WebAPI, OData And EF](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-kendo-ui-with-mvc4-webapi-odata-and-ef) which focussed on the 'inlinecount' param but for me the culprit was the 'format' param.

I'm pasting the summary from that page here in case the link goes bad.

### Remove Inline Count Parameter

```js
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "/api/Albums", // <-- Get data from here
        dataType: "json" // <-- The default was "jsonp"
    },
    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
        var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);
        delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter
        delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter

        return paramMap;
    }
}
```