# How can I fix an error using $select in a Graph API query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using a Microsoft Graph API, specifically `https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/auditLogs/signIns`.

I can use `$filter` and `$orderBy` etc., but if I try to use `$select`, I get an error:

> Query option 'Select' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings`

Where. in my query,. would I put that property? Or is it a server-side thing I can't do anything about?

Comment: we looks like have  the same question here:https://stackoverflow.com/q/25874020

Comment: It's a server side message. It means that select query parameter is not supported

Answer (score -1):

The query is failing because that the `auditLogs/signIns` endpoint does not support `$select`. This is limitation is documented in [Optional query parameters section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) of the [List signIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

The message itself is a bug. This error should *only* get returned in preproduction/debug environment. The proper response *should* be a